# Angular Cognito issue: Cannot read property 'user' of null at authorization.service.ts:29

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, registration

I am trying to implement this POC of AWS Cognito and API Gateway for understanding purposes. According to the video, I have added my own UserPoolId and ClientId in **authorization.service.ts** and I managed to serve the app successfully on localhost:4200. However, I am unable to register an account on my userpool in AWS console.

References for the video explanation and source code:

- Video Credits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROwjNYlxMAs&t=741s&ab_channel=TKousek
- Source Code: https://github.com/kousekt/angularcognitotest

Relevant component ts file in source code for references:

- register.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {AuthorizationService} from "../shared/authorization.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js
// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent { 
  confirmCode: boolean = false;
  codeWasConfirmed: boolean = false;
  error: string = "";
  
  constructor(private auth: AuthorizationService,
              private _router: Router) { }

  register(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.auth.register(email, password).subscribe(
      (data) => {        
        this.confirmCode = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.error = "Registration Error has occurred";
      }
    );
  }

  validateAuthCode(form: NgForm) {
    const code = form.value.code;
    
    this.auth.confirmAuthCode(code).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        //this._router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.codeWasConfirmed = true;
        this.confirmCode = false;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.error = "Confirm Authorization Error has occurred";
      });
  }
}
```

- authorization.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserPool} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const poolData = {
  UserPoolId: 'ap-southeast-1_4E5c8sOtF', // Your user pool id here
  ClientId: '307efnv599eldkq3odcld2j3dh' // Your client id here  
};

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationService {
  cognitoUser: any;

  constructor() { }

  register(email, password) {

    const attributeList = [];

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      userPool.signUp(email, password, attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("signUp error", err);
          observer.error(err);
        }

        this.cognitoUser = result.user;
        console.log("signUp success", result);
        observer.next(result);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });

  }

  confirmAuthCode(code) {
    const user = {
      Username : this.cognitoUser.username,
      Pool : userPool
    };
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(user);
      cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(code, true, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          observer.error(err);
        }
        console.log("confirmAuthCode() success", result);
        observer.next(result);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }

  signIn(email, password) { 

    const authenticationData = {
      Username : email,
      Password : password,
    };
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    const userData = {
      Username : email,
      Pool : userPool
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    
    return Observable.create(observer => {

      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
          
          //console.log(result);
          observer.next(result);
          observer.complete();
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          observer.error(err);
        },
      });
    });
  }

  isLoggedIn() {    
    return userPool.getCurrentUser() != null;
  }

  getAuthenticatedUser() {
    // gets the current user from the local storage
    return userPool.getCurrentUser();
  }

  logOut() {
    this.getAuthenticatedUser().signOut();
    this.cognitoUser = null;
  }
}
```

[Console Error log when registering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drqs1.png)

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to invalidate answers. If there are new issues, you will want to start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

your error doesn't stop the flow, and that is why your code is trying the execute the next line. to fix that just add return here

```
if (err) {
   console.log("signUp error", err);
   observer.error(err);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps to resolve the flow. However, there is this error: "POST https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ 400". Have verified my userpoolid and clientid again.